# Cannot resolve method 'format' in Cucumber reporting

Tags: selenium, cucumber

[image]
Trying to run a cucumber scenario with reporting to a JSON file, but for some reason the 'format' isn't working. It states 'cannot resolve method 'format'. I'm following a tutorial and can't understand why this isn't working. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

working with selenium/java/intelliJ/testNG

Comment: Exactly. Thanks a lot for question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace **format** with **plugin** as format option was deprecated from V. 1.2.0 onwards on 30-October-2014. Example below -

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:features/functional/",
                     glue = {"com.jacksparrow.automation.steps_definitions.functional" },
                   plugin = { "pretty","json:target/cucumber-json/cucumber.json",
                            "junit:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.xml", "html:target/cucumber-reports"},
                   tags = { "@BAMS_Submitted_State_Guest_User" },
                   strict = false,
                   dryRun = false,
               monochrome = true)
```

Comment: where would I go to find out options that are out of date such as this?

Comment: I had a look a documentation regarding this but couldn't find anything

Comment: You shall check https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md to note down changes being implemented after every release.